# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\cos (\pi/n)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\cos (\pi/n)$$

converge or diverge?

Comment: Here's a hint to try to get to the answer yourself: you need to use the limit test

Comment: The given series does not converge but it is instructive to show that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\{1 - \cos(\pi/n)\}$ converges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(\pi/n)$?

Comment: sorry I forgot it was cos, its 1

Comment: So if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(\pi/n)=1$, what can you say about $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\cos (\pi/n)$?

Comment: so I am assuming its definetly gonna diverge

Comment: What is a necessary criteria for a series to be convergent?

Comment: also that lim$a_n$ must approach 0 as n approaches infinity